# Sending an email for values that exceed a limit

Tags: excel, vba, email, basic

When I try to execute the following code, the debugger is highlighting the line strbody which decides which cells get output to the email.

I'm not sure how to activate the FormulaCell so that when a value is exceeded in a column this row will be able to used to enter information to the email.

```
Option Explicit
Public FormulaCell As Range

    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim FormulaRange As Range
    Dim NotSentMsg As String
    Dim MyMsg As String
    Dim SentMsg As String
    Dim MyLimit As Double

    NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
    SentMsg = "Sent"

    'Above the MyLimit value it will run the macro
    MyLimit = 1

    'Set the range with Formulas that you want to check
    Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("B3:B197")

    On Error GoTo EndMacro:
    For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
        With FormulaCell
            If IsNumeric(.Value) = False Then
                MyMsg = "Not numeric"
            Else
                If .Value = MyLimit Then
                    MyMsg = SentMsg
                    If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                        Call Mail_with_outlook2
                    End If
                Else
                    MyMsg = NotSentMsg
                End If
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    Next FormulaCell

    ExitMacro:
    Exit Sub

    EndMacro:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
         & vbLf & Err.Number _
         & vbLf & Err.Description

    End Sub
```

**MACRO**

```
Option Explicit

Public FormulaCell As Range

Sub Mail_with_outlook1()
'For mail code examples visit my mail page at:
'http://www.rondebruin.nl/sendmail.htm
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strto As String, strcc As String, strbcc As String
Dim strsub As String, strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strto = "ron@something.abc"
strcc = ""
strbcc = ""
strsub = "Customers"
strbody = "Hi Ron" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "The total Customers of all stores this week is : " & Cells(FormulaCell.row, "B").Value & _
          vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Good job"

With OutMail
    .To = strto
    .CC = strcc
    .BCC = strbcc
    .Subject = strsub
    .Body = strbody
    'You can add a file to the mail like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Display    ' or use .Send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub Mail_with_outlook2()
'For mail code examples visit my mail page at:
'http://www.rondebruin.nl/sendmail.htm
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strto As String, strcc As String, strbcc As String
Dim strsub As String, strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strto = "MAIL@EMAIL.CO.UK"
strcc = ""
strbcc = ""
strsub = "S888 OVERDUE"
strbody = "THIS S888 IS NOW OVERDUE" & Cells(FormulaCell.row, "A").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "Your total of this week is : " & Cells(FormulaCell.row, "K:Q").Value & _
          vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "HURRY UP!!"

With OutMail
    .To = strto
    .CC = strcc
    .BCC = strbcc
    .Subject = strsub
    .Body = strbody
    'You can add a file to the mail like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Display    ' or use .Send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

as Vityata already stated, the expression `Cells(FormulaCell.row, "K:Q").Value` isn't valid

if you need a reference to cells in column K to Q in the same row as `FormulaCell` Range then use

```
Worksheetfunction.Sum(Intersect(FormulaCell.EntireRow, Range("K:Q")))
```

So if you wanted to return the sum of those cells then use

```
strbody = "THIS S888 IS NOW OVERDUE" & Cells(FormulaCell.row, "A").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "Your total of this week is : " & Worksheetfunction.Sum(Intersect(FormulaCell.EntireRow, Range("K:Q"))) & _
      vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "HURRY UP!!"
```

But there I see a **hidden bug** in your code where you use `Public FormulaCell As Range` both in `Worksheet_Calculate()` event handler and in your "MACRO" Module

By doing so, in you're instantiating two different `Range` variables, one attached to the worksheet event handler and one to the MACRO module, and without explicitly qualifying them up to their *Parent* object you would reference the `Range` variable in the currently "active" VBA module.

So, in your code before executing `Call Mail_with_outlook2` statement, any `FormulaCell` would reference the current iterator `Range` variable of your `For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells` loop. But as soon as the program execution gets into `Mail_with_outlook2()` the "resident" `FormulaCell` variable is still to be set and so it's `Nothing`

Long story short you have two choices:

- get rid of `Public FormulaCell As Range` in MACRO module and explicitly qualify all `FormulaCell` references up to the `Sheet` object where the `Worksheet_Calculate()` resides

  for example, assuming "Sheet1" is the name of this latter, then you'd write:

  ```
  strbody = "Hi Ron" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "The total Customers of all stores this week is : " & Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").FormulaCell.Row, "B").value & _
    vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Good job"
  ```
- get rid of all `Public FormulaCell As Range` in both Worksheet and MACRO module and have `Mail_with_outlook1()` sub accept a "FormulaCell" `Range` parameter

  so in `Worksheet_Calculate()`, instead of:

  ```
  Call Mail_with_outlook2
  ```

  you'd have:

  ```
  Mail_with_outlook2 FormulaCell
  ```

  and in `Mail_with_outlook1()`, instead of:

  ```
  Sub Mail_with_outlook1()
  ```

  you'd have

  ```
  Sub Mail_with_outlook1(FormulaCell As Range)
  ```

Comment: @RyanLigget, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this here:

`Cells(FormulaCell.row, "K:Q").Value` Depending on what you need, try like this:

```
Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "K").Value
Range("K" & FormulaCell.Row & ":Q" & FormulaCell.Row).Values
```

Or something else.

In general, whenever you think that the error is somewhere you know, try to make the code as smaller as possible and to see whether it runs. In your case something small is this one:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strBody As String

    For Each FormulaCell In Range("A1:A2")
        strBody = "Hi Ron" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "The total Customers of all stores this week is : " _
        & Cells(FormulaCell.Row, "B").Value & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Good job"
        Debug.Print strBody
    Next FormulaCell

End Sub
```